# Qué quiere decir esta expresión : "var b = s == null;"

Tags: javascript

No sé qué significa, y no sé cómo o dónde puedo buscar información al respecto. Agradecería que alguien me explicara su funcionamiento, y el nombre que reciben este tipo de expresiones, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que se está haciendo es decir que `b` va a valer el resultado de comparar el contenido de `s` con `null`, de tal manera que si `s` vale `null` entonces `b` será `true` y si vale cualquier cosa que no sea `null` lo que valdrá `b` es `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dando por hecho que es lenguaje Javascript.

Se está declarando una variable, b, y se le está asingnando un valor que es el resultado de comparar el valor de la variable s con null (valor nulo). Si la comparación es positiva, b recibirá e valor true, y si es negativa, recibirá false. Ojo, si la variable s no existe (no está declarada previamente) se producirá un error.

Esa expresión es por tanto una instrucción donde hay una declaración, una asignación y una comparación.

No obstante, no es recomendable usarla tal cual, es preferible usar paréntesis para dejar claro qué se hace primero, en vez de dejarlo al lenguaje, que puede llevar a confusión. Así que ponemos paréntesis para dejar claro que primero queremos que se haga la comparación, que coincidide con cómo lo hace el lenguaje, pero lo dejamos claro para evitar equívocos:

```
var b = (s == null);
```

Ejemplo para probar:

```
var s = 'Hola';
var b = (s == null);
alert(b); //Mostrará false
```

Comment: Entiendo, el fragmento lo saqué de una parte de código escrito en c#, pero aun así resolviste mi duda, gracias!